# connecting to oracle timesten via cx_oracle in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle, timesten

I can connect to oracle via cx_Oracle in sqlalchemy by this connection string:

```
connection_string = 'oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@127.0.0.1/orcl'
```

and also i can connect TimesTen by cx_Oracle using this:

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass@127.0.0.1/tt2:timestendirect')
```

but i don't know how to connect to TimesTen via cx_Oracle in sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create an entry in the TNSNAMES.ora configuration file and then use that directly. If you are using the instant client, you can set the environment variable TNS_ADMIN to point to a directory of your choosing that contains the tnsnames.ora configuration file.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/timesten.112/e13066/oci.htm#BABHAAHJ

The easy connect syntax does not appear to be supported by sqlalchemy.